# Is a WU-1a WiFi adapter secure?

Tags: nikon, file-transfer, wifi, security

Let's say I am shooting using Nikon D3200 and I am using the external WU-1a Wifi adapter to transfer the images from the camera to my smartphone, and in a party. Is it possible that someone else with the Nikon Android App "Wireless Mobile Utility" on his or her smartphone could connect his or her smartphone to my camera and grab all or some of my photos stored in my camera?

I know the Nikon Android app [Wireless Mobile Utility](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nikon.wu.wmau) says that "Only one camera can be connected at a time", but due to connection unstability that users reporting over the app store webpage, could it be connected to anyone using the same app on his or her smartphone, while my own connection with the camera is unstable?

How can I prevent unauthorized access to my Camera while I am using the "WU-1a Wifi adapter"?

Comment: You would want to make sure that you are using WPA-CCMP with a strong password.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use the Nikon WMU (Wireless Mobile Utility), it allows you to create wifi networks that are secured, but by default, it will create an unsecured network.  To set up a password protected network, you have to configure the wireless adapter, and the device the WMU app is installed on.

Comment: It is the first time I know I can configure my adapter. How to do that please?

Comment: http://nikonasia-en.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/7566/~/wu-1a-wireless-mobile-adapter-setup

Comment: Can you edit that link into the answer, Don?